# How to pass a command from Shell script to command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am using ssh on my linux to remote access a second linux. What ssh does is to make my Linux's Terminal the remote Linux's Terminal, and whatever I entered in my Terminal would be executed on the remote Linux. Now I want to use a Shell script to enter a command after the remote access has been established.

I use the following bash to do the ssh part:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@192.168.178.160
```

after this it prompts a password which is fine, I enter the password and the I am connected to the remote host.
but after that I need to enter some additional commands to be executed automatically ( also from shell script) but simply entering them after the above code lines doesn't work.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell `ssh` to send them to the remote shell to be executed.

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@192.168.178.160 << EOF
./foo bar 42
cat baz/quux
EOF
```

Comment: This creates an interactive session. On my machine this means I get a "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." warning and also the multi-line "Welcome to Ubuntu" login message.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams great it works, but it executes the second one after the first one is done, adding & to end of lines doesn't work either?
can i somehow execute them simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Put the command at the end:

```
ssh user@192.168.178.160 echo foobar
```

To execute multiple commands, use a multi-line string:

```
ssh user@192.168.178.160 '
    echo foo
    echo bar
'
```